# Get information for an "unique id" from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this structure:

```
Array
(
    [mysite] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => uniqueid
                    [1] => brand
                    [2] => horsepower
                    [3] => topspeed
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => uniqueid
                    [1] => brand
                    [2] => horsepower
                    [3] => topspeed
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => uniqueid
                    [1] => brand
                    [2] => horsepower
                    [3] => topspeed
                )
        )
)
```

Every car has an "uniqueid" followed by brand, horsepower, etc.

If I want to get the information for a **random car**, I do it like this:

```
$rkey = array_rand($sites['mysite'], 1); // get a random key
$car_info = $myarray['mysite'][$rkey];
```

**Do you have any ideas on how to get information by using a certain "uniqueid"**

```
$car_info = "get the information of a car with a certain uniqueid";
```

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

Pass unique id inside the for loop you will get the desird result
It may help you,

```
$array = array(

  0   => Array
            (
                0 => 'uniqueid0',
                1 => 'brand',
                2 => 'horsepower',
                3 => 'topspeed',
            ),
  1   => Array
            (
                0 => 'uniqueid1',
                1 => 'brand',
                2 => 'horsepower',
                3 => 'topspeed',
            ),
  2  => Array
            (
                0 => 'uniqueid2',
                1 => 'brand',
                2 => 'horsepower',
                3 => 'topspeed',
            ),
  3  => Array
            (
                0 => 'uniqueid3',
                1 => 'brand',
                2 => 'horsepower',
                3 => 'topspeed',
            ),
);


  foreach($array as $arr){
    if($arr[0] == 'uniqueid2'){
      $result = $arr;
      break;
    }
  }
```

print_r($result );

output:

Array ( [0] => uniqueid2 [1] => brand [2] => horsepower [3] => topspeed )

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniqueid = 12345;

foreach ($myarray['mysite'] as $car) {
    if($car[0] == $uniqueid) {
        $car_info = $car;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for answering. Why use $rkey?

Answer (score 0):

if the uniqueid is unique across cars then you can try restructure the array as follows

if possible

```
Array (
    [mysite] => Array
    (
        [uniqueid1] => Array
            (
                [0] => uniqueid1
                [1] => brand
                [2] => horsepower
                [3] => topspeed
            )

        [uniqueid2] => Array
            (
                [0] => uniqueid2
                [1] => brand
                [2] => horsepower
                [3] => topspeed
            )

        [uniqueid3] => Array
            (
                [0] => uniqueid3
                [1] => brand
                [2] => horsepower
                [3] => topspeed
            )
    )
)
```

this way you can directly access the car for uniqueid and can also apply random logic

if not @Jevgeni Bogatyrjov  solution works well

```
foreach ($myarray['mysite'] as $car) {
    if($car[0] == $uniqueid) {
        $car_info = $car;
        break;
    }
}
```